# ajax sending 400 bad request error in wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

Hi everyone i am trying to use ajax in wordpress and got stuck in something. My code is giving me an error in console as

```
    jquery-3.3.1.js:9600 GET http://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php 400 (Bad Request)
send @ jquery-3.3.1.js:9600
ajax @ jquery-3.3.1.js:9206
(anonymous) @ main.js?ver=1:27
dispatch @ jquery-3.3.1.js:5183
elemData.handle @ jquery-3.3.1.js:4991
```

I looked into the source and it is showing me the error on this line

```
xhr.send( options.hasContent && options.data || null );
```

This is my jquery

```
$('#retrieve_users').click(function() {

    $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: scriptData.ajaxurl,
            action : 'retrieveUsersData',
            dataType: "html",   //expect html to be returned                
            success: function(response)
            {                    
                $("#users_data").html(response); 
                //alert(response);
            }
        });
});
```

This is my php code in functions.php file

```
function retrieveUsersData(){

echo "ajax responding";
}

add_action('wp_ajax_retrieveUsersData','retrieveUsersData');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_retrieveUsersData', 'retrieveUsersData');
```

and this is my html

```
<button id="retrieve_users">Watch Users</button>
                <div id="users_data"></div>
```

Please help!! I didnt know how to import jquery src link in wordpress using wp_enque_scripts so i pasted the  with jquery src directly in html. I hope its not creating problem

Please help.. i would really appreciate it. Thank you

Comment: `$.ajax` doesn't have an `action` property. You need to pass that in the request, presumably as part of the URL, depending on how your routing is configured

Comment: I am not sure but the way I was doing was to use `POST` and in the body object pass the `action` key.

Comment: if possible can you please suggest the code. i am kinda confused. Thank you!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change your code to use `POST` and in the body of the request use the action key :

```
jQuery.ajax({
            url: scriptData.ajaxurl,
            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'html',
            data: {
                action: 'retrieveUsersData'
            },

            ...
});
```

Also you should use `wp_die()` in the function to prevent the `0` to be echoed.

```
function retrieveUsersData(){
    echo "ajax responding";
    wp_die();
}
```

Comment: @NageshKatna glad I could help. You can accept the answer also (not only thumb it up) ;)

Comment: Yes @AnatoliiBivol i am doing so.. stakoverflow is not allowing me to do so in 3 minutes.. so waiting for the 3 minutes to finish.. Lol!!