# How to post to php with ajax, I consistently get error 400 bad request?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress, post

I am trying to send a "POST" request to my backend PHP code, which resides in functions.php in Wordpress. I get a readystate:4 and bad request(400 status) error when I run the code, if I change the "POST" to "GET" it works.

This is not the first time I encounter this, but previously it has been in my spare time projects, this time it is for work. as mentioned above I can "solve" it by changing the method to "GET", but that is not the method you are supposed to use when you add to your database. I've tried to comment out the lines with "dataType", "contentType", and "processData", but it doesn't make a difference I still just get a bad request(400) error. I have several "GET"s that work fine elsewhere in functions.php and urlen is pointing directly to functions.php.

**JS**

```
function AddToTable(){ 
   Data={"action":"CreateProduct","Password":Password.value,"Varenr":Varenr.value,"Produkttype":Produkttype.value,"Navn":Navn.value,"Billede":Billede.value,"BilledeAlt":BilledeAlt.value,"Farve":Farve.value,"Tykkelse":Tykkelse.value,"Pris":Pris.value};

   jQuery.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: urlen,
       dataType: "json",
       contentType: "application/json",
       processData: false,
       data: JSON.stringify(Data),
       success: successfunction,
       error: errorfunction,
   });

   function successfunction(data){
       RefreshTable();
   }

   function errorfunction(data, status) {
       alert("error: "+status+" Content: " + JSON.stringify(data));
   };
}
```

**Functions.php**

```
<?php
function CreateProduct(){
 exit;
}

add_action('wp_ajax_CreateProduct','CreateProduct');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_CreateProduct','CreateProduct');
?>
```

I expect it to send the data to the server function, so I can do more with it there. But I get a readystate:4 and state 400 errorcode.

UPDATED: to include the Functions.php part of the code.

Comment: Can you log the content of `urlen` ?

Comment: Is your request arriving to the server controller?

Comment: It works fine for my other "GET"s calling functions.php so it isn't the cause of the error, but sure: "https://MyWebPage/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php"

Comment: please post complete code including code in functions.php, you cannot call ajax directly in wordpress, it needs priv_ajax functions from functions.php and matching action hook

Comment: The error 400 is a bad request. Meaning that something in the request is malformed and the server will refuse to process it. If I have to guess it is the url you are calling that is wrong. You have to degug it and fix it.

Comment: @mgarcia I don't think so, right now just for testing it is calling a function that just exits. If it succesfully arrived, it should return status: 200 as it doesn't do anything it could fail at.

Comment: Can you try this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/48689923/507203  passing data with `action`

Comment: @charan kumar I updated it to include functions.php as it looks right now, but as I said I already call other functions succesfully from it, so I'm pretty sure that the error happens before it gets there.

Comment: @cjmling, I already do, second line of code, and as far as I can see from the requestheader it converts it correctly to a json array when it is sent.

Comment: @Lelio Faieta the url is correct, I call other functions in functions.php on the same website succesfully before I get to this function. I also posted the url above in another comment.

Comment: I've fiddled around with it and I can get the whole thing to work using Get instead of Post, but when I switch it to Post I get a Bad Request. It is not urlen that is the problem not if the Get works.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your data to be posted is malformed.
You have prepared it like

```
Data={"action":"CreateProduct","Password":Password.value,"Varenr":Varenr.value,"Produkttype":Produkttype.value,"Navn":Navn.value,"Billede":Billede.value,"BilledeAlt":BilledeAlt.value,"Farve":Farve.value,"Tykkelse":Tykkelse.value,"Pris":Pris.value};
```

Variables to be posted should not be in quotes so your code there should begin like

```
Data={action:"CreateProduct",Password: Password.value,Varenr: Varenr.value, .....
```

and so on

Comment: No, they're just the same and are both valid after stringify to json string

Comment: I tried this and it really doesn't make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

A GET request to a URL will simply tell you whether or not it exists, in basic terms.  If you send a GET request to cnn.com it will respond with a 200, if send a GET to cnnbootyshort.com, you will get no response.

In your case, rather than using exit, you could try using die(), along with an echo of what you want to send back to the browser.

```
    <?php
     function CreateProduct(){
     echo "200";
     die();
     }

     add_action('wp_ajax_CreateProduct','CreateProduct');
     add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_CreateProduct','CreateProduct');
    ?>
```

And your JS

```
    function successfunction(data){
      console.log(data); // for debugging
      RefreshTable();
    }

   function errorfunction(data, status) {
     console.log(data); // for debugging
     alert("error: "+status+" Content: " + JSON.stringify(data));
    };
```

Alternatively you can use wp_die() if you want to use a Wordpress specific function.  [Here is some documentation regarding its use](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_die/).

```
     <?php
     function CreateProduct(){

     wp_die();
     }

     add_action('wp_ajax_CreateProduct','CreateProduct');
     add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_CreateProduct','CreateProduct');
    ?>
```

Comment: I can get the function to work with Get, but not with Post, with Post I get a Bad Request error. The php function is not supposed to deliver anything back to the browser, it is supposed to add data to an SQL database.